# how to change keyboard type in TextField when change a Tab?

Tags: flutter, focus, textfield, tabbar

I want to change the keyboard type dynamic when user changes a Tab in TabBarView. I Tried a lot of things `autoFocus = true`, give `FocusNode()` for each `TextField` and unfocus and request focus for these focusNode. The same FocusNode for these three TextField.

[image]

**Things that I already tried**

```
return TabBar(
      onTap: (_) {
        if (tabController.indexIsChanging) {
//here the input just unfocus



          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((v) {
             FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus();
          });

        }
      }, ... )
```

**my TextField**

```
 Widget _buildTextField({
    TextInputType keyboardType,
    List<TextInputFormatter> inputFormatters,

  }) {
    return BlocBuilder<TransferBloc, TransferState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return TextField(
          controller: inputController,
          // focusNode: focusInput,
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
}
)
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your example code but if there is only a single field in each view, `autofocus` should be enough. https://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/NWGJWPO

Comment: thanks for the example, but don't solve my problem. The user don't have to tap in TextField to open a keyboard. The app should do it automatic.

Comment: The keyboard should open automatically when the text field is focused.

Comment: yes, but the user don't have to tap in TextField to focus. It should be done automatically when the tab is changing

Comment: That is whats happening in my example, there is just no keyboard in Web but the field is focused.

Comment: thanks for your time @kuhnroyal but I tested it on simulator and keyboard dont up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

this solves my problem but sounds like a hack.
Does someone have a better approach?

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 350)).then((value) {
       FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(inputFocus);
});
```

less than 350 milliseconds don't work. :/